# Finding bonds for atoms in a molecule using python doesn't work correctly

Tags: python-3.x

I have this data that contains distances between atoms in a molecule:

```
data = [['', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'O'],
['C', '0.0000', '2.1132', '2.1135', '2.7646', '2.7635', '2.3236'],
['H', '2.1132', '0.0000', '1.7428', '3.0699', '2.5267', '3.0436'],
['H', '2.1135', '1.7428', '0.0000', '2.5262', '3.0699', '3.0054'],
['H', '2.7646', '3.0699', '2.5262', '0.0000', '1.7451', '4.8540'],
['H', '2.7635', '2.5267', '3.0699', '1.7451', '0.0000', '4.8774'],
['O', '2.3236', '3.0436', '3.0054', '4.8540', '4.8774', '0.0000']]
```

So for example the last value on the second row (`data[1][6]`) is the distance between C and O atoms. I want to find out which atoms are bound to each other in this molecule. This is done using distance ranges typical for each pair of atoms.

I tried to do it like this:

```
def find_heavy_bonds(data):
    """Function finds bonds from heavy atoms (heavy meaning anything else than hydrogen)"""
    new_data = data

    C_C_min, C_C_max = 1.50 - 0.005, 1.50 + 0.005
    C_N_min, C_N_max = 1.40 - 0.005, 1.40 + 0.005
    C_O_min, C_O_max = 1.23 - 0.005, 1.23 + 0.005

    for num1, row in enumerate(new_data):
        for num2, element in enumerate(row):
            if num1 > 0 and num2 > 0:
                atom1 = new_data[num1][0]
                atom2 = new_data[0][num2]
                if atom1 == "C" and atom2 == "C" and C_C_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_C_max:
                    new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"
                elif atom1 == "C" and atom2 == "N" or atom1 == "N" and atom2 == "C"\
                        and C_N_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_N_max:
                    new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"
                elif atom1 == "C" and atom2 == "O" or atom1 == "O" and atom2 == "C"\
                        and C_O_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_O_max:
                    new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"

    return new_data
```

But when I write:

```
final = find_heavy_bonds(data)
for row in final:
    print(row)
```

I get this:

```
['', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'O']
['C', '0.0000', '2.1132', '2.1135', '2.7646', '2.7635', 'BOND']
['H', '2.1132', '0.0000', '1.7428', '3.0699', '2.5267', '3.0436']
['H', '2.1135', '1.7428', '0.0000', '2.5262', '3.0699', '3.0054']
['H', '2.7646', '3.0699', '2.5262', '0.0000', '1.7451', '4.8540']
['H', '2.7635', '2.5267', '3.0699', '1.7451', '0.0000', '4.8774']
['O', '2.3236', '3.0436', '3.0054', '4.8540', '4.8774', '0.0000']
```

There is only 1 bond which is between C and O but it shouldn't be there since the distance between C and O is 2.3236 and typical distance range for C and O is [1.23 - 0.005, 1.23 + 0.005]. And even if there was a bond, I also should have 'BOND' in `data[6][1]` since it is exactly the same distance between the same pair of atoms.

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the conditions the same way you would group operations. `(3 + 1) * 4` is not the same than `3 + (1 * 4)`.

```
def find_heavy_bonds(data):
    """Function finds bonds from heavy atoms (heavy meaning anything else than hydrogen)"""
    new_data = data

    C_C_min, C_C_max = 1.50 - 0.005, 1.50 + 0.005
    C_N_min, C_N_max = 1.40 - 0.005, 1.40 + 0.005
    C_O_min, C_O_max = 1.23 - 0.005, 1.23 + 0.005

    for num1, row in enumerate(new_data):
        for num2, element in enumerate(row):
            if num1 > 0 and num2 > 0:
                atom1 = new_data[num1][0]
                atom2 = new_data[0][num2]
                if atom1 == "C" and atom2 == "C" and C_C_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_C_max:
                    new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"
                elif ((atom1 == "C" and atom2 == "N") or (atom1 == "N" and atom2 == "C"))\
                        and C_N_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_N_max:
                    new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"
                elif ((atom1 == "C" and atom2 == "O") or (atom1 == "O" and atom2 == "C"))\
                        and C_O_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_O_max:
                    new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"

    return new_data
```

If you want to make the conditions a bit shorter, you could use the following syntax:

```
def find_heavy_bonds(data):
    """Function finds bonds from heavy atoms (heavy meaning anything else than hydrogen)"""
    new_data = data

    C_C_min, C_C_max = 1.50 - 0.005, 1.50 + 0.005
    C_N_min, C_N_max = 1.40 - 0.005, 1.40 + 0.005
    C_O_min, C_O_max = 1.23 - 0.005, 1.23 + 0.005

    for num1, row in enumerate(new_data):
        for num2, element in enumerate(row):
            if num1 > 0 and num2 > 0:
                atoms = new_data[num1][0], new_data[0][num2]
                if atoms == ("C", "C") and C_C_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_C_max:
                    new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"
                elif (atoms == ("C", "N") or atoms == ("N", "C")) \
                        and C_N_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_N_max:
                    new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"
                elif (atoms == ("C", "O") or atoms == ("O", "C")) \
                        and C_O_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_O_max:
                    new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"

    return new_data
```

A last modification you could make is split the conditions into two ifs. The reasoning behind this change is that, if you get to the correct if atom-wise but the distance is not a bond, you will check every other condition in the if-elif block, while with two ifs this won't happen:

```
def find_heavy_bonds(data):
    """Function finds bonds from heavy atoms (heavy meaning anything else than hydrogen)"""
    new_data = data

    C_C_min, C_C_max = 1.50 - 0.005, 1.50 + 0.005
    C_N_min, C_N_max = 1.40 - 0.005, 1.40 + 0.005
    C_O_min, C_O_max = 1.23 - 0.005, 1.23 + 0.005

    for num1, row in enumerate(new_data):
        for num2, element in enumerate(row):
            if num1 > 0 and num2 > 0:
                atoms = new_data[num1][0], new_data[0][num2]
                if atoms == ("C", "C"):
                    if C_C_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_C_max:
                        new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"
                elif (atoms == ("C", "N") or atoms == ("N", "C")):
                    if C_N_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_N_max:
                        new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"
                elif (atoms == ("C", "O") or atoms == ("O", "C")):
                    if C_O_min <= float(new_data[num1][num2]) <= C_O_max:
                        new_data[num1][num2] = "BOND"

    return new_data
```